# Why the sign for \$4Ω\$ resistor is positive using KVL even though it dissipates heat?

Tags: kirchhoffs-laws

I would like to know why the sign for \$4Ω\$ resistor is positive as the equation in the image shows

\$-I1∙8Ω+I2∙4Ω=0\$

Even though the equation is formed using [KVL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kirchhoff%27s_circuit_laws#Kirchhoff.27s_voltage_law_.28KVL.29) why the sign for \$4Ω\$ resistor is positive when it actually should be negative since it dissipates heat?
[image: Circuit Analysis]

Comment: Negative voltage x Negative current = Positive power. The -I1 x 8ohm term is a negative voltage, not a negative power.

Comment: @MarkU:Sorry I couldn't see anything related to power here.Did you mean to say voltage?

Comment: "why the sign ... should be negative since it dissipates heat?" So you're saying resistors can also **undissipate** heat ? Thank about that for a moment. Take a 9V battery and a 220 - 470 ohm resistor. Connect the resistor across the battery, it gets warm. Now reverse the battery's polarity, does it still get warm or does it cool down ? Does the direction of the current affect the resistor's dissipation ?

Comment: @FakeMoustache:I'm saying that resistors **dissipate** heat and that's why I asked why doesn't the \$4Ω\$ resistor doesn't contain a negative sign when it actually dissipates heat.

Comment: You mentioned "because it dissipates heat", and heat means power. If the KVL equation is formed by going around the loop (mesh) that goes around the unnamed 8ohm resistor and the 4ohm resistor, from A to B and back again, then the algebraic sum of those voltages must be 0V: I2 * 4ohm - I1 * 8ohm = 0volts.

Comment: The KVL loop is taken **clockwise**, from node B through 8ohm R, node A through 4ohm R back to node B. Now **write the KVL again** but go through the same loop but **counterclockwise**. Now which term is negative ? Did anything change physically ??

Comment: By the way, this is why any real schematic would have reference designators to name each component. It's much clearer to write I2*R2 - I1*R1 = 0, where R1=8ohm and R2=4ohm.

Comment: You confuse yourself and others by coupling the **sign** of the current to **heat dissipation** while the two are **unrelated**. The **magnitude** of the current relates to the heat dissipation, not the sign or direction.

Comment: For this trivial example you can see by inspection that R1 and R2 both have to have the same voltage, but they want you to see that you go around a complete circuit loop (or mesh) to write a KVL equation, no matter how many components in the loop.

Comment: For KVL, you can write the equation either "clockwise" or "couterclockwise", the algebraic signs of the terms get inverted but the net result is the same as long as you're consistent. Same with KCL, write the equation with positive = inbound current or positive = outbound current, either way works, just be consistent.

Comment: @MarkU:It's true by [KVL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kirchhoff%27s_circuit_laws#Kirchhoff.27s_voltage_law_.28KVL.29) that the sign is positive for R2.SInce R1 and R2 have the same properties of a resistor shouldn't both of these have the same sign

Comment: KVL only deals with conservation of voltage going around a circuit loop. Conservation of energy is a valid concept, but the terms in KVL are not energy terms. Power = Voltage x Current. (Power is time rate of change of Energy.) The KVL terms are Voltage = Current x Resistance. Each term in the KVL equation is a voltage, not a power.

Comment: @FakeMoustache:That should be true perhaps.Even if that's the case shouldn't both resistors have the same sign?Is there any difference in the sign or direction of flow of current in R1 and R2?

Comment: If you were writing an equation for power dissipated by R1 and R2, that would be P = I1*I1*R1 + I2*I2*R2; and since the current is squared, it doesn't matter whether the current is negative or positive.

Comment: @MarkU:Could you tell whether there's any difference in the sign or direction of flow of current in R1 and R2.

Comment: *shouldn't both resistors have the same sign?* The sign is just that **a sign** it gives **no indication** of the **actual direction of current flow**. You're linking the **mathematical variables** to **physical entities** already why none have been determined yet. Imagine that the current is zero and no power is dissipated ! Does the KVL then suddenly not hold anymore ? No it doesn't. Because it relates to the circuit or network. Not to how much current is actually flowing.

Comment: The sign of the current does matter when determining the voltage, V=I*R. The sign of the current does not matter when determining the power dissipation, P=I*I*R. The square of a negative value is a positive value.

Comment: @MarkU:As per your equation isn't the sign of  _V_ really depended on the sign of _I_?

Comment: No it is not ! You really should learn that **the sign does not matter**. You choose it to whatever you like, and then follow mathematical rules and not worry about the sign anymore. Try it and see that that just works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're a little confused, dissipation of power as heat isn't used anywhere in KVL. That comes into play when you're calculating things like efficiency and losses.

Firstly I think that question is laid out in a bit of a strange way. What they're trying to say is that the voltage drop across the \$8\Omega
\$ resistor is the same as the voltage drop across the \$4\Omega
\$ resistor. A more sensible way to write this would be \$I_{1}*8\Omega = I_{2}*4\Omega\$ or \$I_{1}*8\Omega - I_{2}*4\Omega = 0\$

The way it's written the way it is, is due to the position of the 'node' they've used (which kindly they haven't put on the circuit for us)

[image]

As for why the resistor doesn't have a negative sign, think about it in terms of a real world example. If you measure a voltage with a multimeter one way you get +12V, you reverse the leads you get -12V. Now if you do the same with a resistor you're going to get the same resistance either way.

Comment: :Do you mean to say if the resistor is held in '-' to '+' direction you get an negative voltage and vice versa?

Comment: **Again** you assume that a negative current gives a negative voltage ! Let go of that value of the current ! For KVL it does not matter what the value or the sign is of the current. Here I1 is just the **mathematical variable** assigned to the current through the 8 ohm resistor. And VAB is the voltage across it. If you reverse the direction of the arrows (for the currents) and/or the + and - of VAB, **it will make no difference for the KVL**.

Comment: @Justin if you're referring to the last paragraph I'm talking about a real world example, it doesn't matter if you put +12V or -12V through a resistor, it doesn't ever change it's value. Just by reversing the voltage and/or current doesn't make a 430R resistor a -430R resistor

Comment: What is needed for KVL is a "reference direction" so you can just **pick one at random** meaning the direction of the arrows (for the currents) and the + and - signs of VAB are **ARBITRARY CHOICES** You can choose them to be **any direction** and KVL will still give the **same result**.

Comment: For example, if I was to reverse the direction of my arrow so that the loop was going counter clockwise then you'd get \$-I2∙4Ω+I1∙8Ω=0\$ but the overall answer doesn't change. The signs are dependant on where your node is and the direction you choose (CW/CCW). But this only affects voltage and current. If you need an even more real world example, think of squeezing a hose with your hand. It doesn't matter which way the water flows through it, just because the water is flowing in reverse doesn't mean your grip on the hose has changed. Think of that as your resistance

Comment: @Hayman:Yeah I can get that.I think I can't get the difference between '-12v' and '+12v' while reversing the leads of mutilmeter.Could you help me.

Comment: No problem. With a multimeter you have a red lead and a black lead. The black lead is known as **common** but you can also think of it as a reference point. Now if we put the black lead at 0V and our red lead at 12V then our multimeter will display '12V' as the red lead is at a point 12V higher than our common (black lead). If we change it now so the black lead is at 12V and our red lead is at 0V then our multimeter will display '-12V' as the red lead is now at a point 12V lower than our common (black lead). Does that make sense now?

Comment: @Hayman:I would like to know why it shows '-12v' or what makes it to show '-12v'.

Comment: That's what I just explained, if your red probe is at a voltage that's 12V lower than your common (black probe) then it will consider it a negative voltage as \$P_{red} - P_{black} = -12V\$.

Comment: @Hayman:Okay.Do you mean to say that '+12v' and '-12v' are equivalent even though it's different based on the reference point?Could you tell what's really '12v' in essence.Is it related to the number of electrons pumped?

Comment: +12V and -12V are equivalent in terms of amplitude, the direction changes based on what you use as your reference point. In terms of electrons, that's more physics and I'm not too sure about all that side of things.

Comment: @Hayman:Let's leave that.Could you tell what comes in your mind when you hear '1.5v'.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/38067/discussion-between-hayman-and-justin).

Comment: @Hayman:Could you tell why the resistance gets _lower_ than the individual resistances when we connect these resistances in parallel.

Comment: http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/137527/why-is-equivalent-resistance-in-parallel-circuit-always-less-than-each-individua

Comment: @Hayman:Could you please join the [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/38067/discussion-between-hayman-and-justin).

Comment: @Hayman:If you have time could you help me with three phase connections that large industries uses.